# Is it possible to both listen and send messages to a remote socket using node-red's websocket node?

Tags: node.js, sockets, automation, node-red

The Almond Plus router and home automation hub now exposes the state of its registered z-wave and zigbee sensors via a websocket.

The websocket API is here:

https://wiki.securifi.com/index.php/Websockets_Documentation

I've aimed a node-red websocket node at the router's local IP address, and have included authentication information in the URL. This seems to work for receiving status changes to devices.

But I need to also be able to send commands over the websocket to flip switches and whatnot. When I create both 'listen on' and 'connect to' websocket nodes in node-red, only the node that's listening connects. Do I need to make two nodes at all? I would have hoped there'd be a way to make one connection to the websocket and use it for two-way communication, but maybe this question just exposes my ignorance of how either websockets or node-red function.

Thanks for any help or information.

Answer (score 0):

You should need both a *Websocket in* and a *Websocket out*, but both should be set to "connect to" mode. These handle the input and output side of the connection

I'd have to double check the code, but they should share the same client connection under the covers so there will only be one real Websocket connection. But even if the 2 nodes don't share the connection having 2 separate websocket connections to the same address shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Looks like the problem was that my remote device wouldn't accept a password that long. Hopefully they fix that in the next firmware update. In the meantime, I'll be changing my password to something compatible.

Thanks for the help.